# JUnit test on recursive function (creating file and compare size)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm working on a project : copy a file and check if the size are equals. If not, delete file and redo it (number of retries is defined)

```
public boolean copieFichierAvecRetry(FileObject copieFichierFile, FileObject fichierACopier, int nbRetry, int currentNbRetry)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    logger.logInfo("Deplacement du fichier " + fichierACopier.getName().getBaseName(),
            "de " + fichierACopier.getParent().getName().getPath() + " vers "
                    + copieFichierFile.getParent().getName().getPath());
    copieFichierFile.copyFrom(fichierACopier, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
    boolean tailleOk = false;
    // Si le flag de vérification est à true on vérifie que les fichiers
    // copies ont la même taille
    try {
        tailleOk = verificationTailleCorrespondantes(copieFichierFile, fichierACopier);
        if (!tailleOk && currentNbRetry <= nbRetry){
            logger.logInfo("Erreur lors de la verification de la taille, essai n°" + currentNbRetry, null);
            copieFichierFile.delete();
            currentNbRetry++;
            copieFichierAvecRetry(copieFichierFile, fichierACopier, nbRetry, currentNbRetry);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.logWarn("Erreur lors de la verification de la taille : ", e.getMessage());
        tailleOk = false;
    }
    return tailleOk;
}
```

Here is the unit test for the non-recursive function :

```
public void testCopieFichier()
        throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException, TransfertFichierException {
    socleUtil.setNbTentativeMaxTransfert(1);
    String nomFichierSource = "test123.txt";
    String nomFichierDestination = "testDownloadSuccess.xml";

    File fileOrigine = new File(getClass().getResource(SocleConstantes.SLASH).getFile());
    String cheminFichierDistantOrigine = fileOrigine.getPath();
    File fileDestination = new File(getClass().getResource(SocleConstantes.SLASH).toURI());
    String cheminFichierDistantDestination = fileDestination.getPath() + FILE_SEPARATOR + "download";

    assertTrue(socleUtil.copieFichier(
            socleUtil.findFileLocal(cheminFichierDistantDestination + "/" + nomFichierDestination),
            socleUtil.findFileLocal(cheminFichierDistantOrigine + "/" + nomFichierSource)));
    assertTrue(fileDestination.exists());
}
```

As you can see in the code above, it will copy a file, check size and if it's OK then return true.
If it's false for 5 times (in the exemple) the function calls itself after deleting the file with wrong size.

- `verificationTailleCorrespondantes` is the function to compare sizes.
- `tailleOk` is true if both files are same size.

How should I test the recursivity of this function if it copies a file and never fail (which happens in production) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd write the following scenarios:

- the process success at its first iteration
- the process fails at its (n-1)th iteration, success at its nth iteration with n < number of retries
- the process fails at its nth iteration with n == number of retries

In order to do it, you'll need to mock your dependencies. Specially the one checking the file size. The mocking for the previous scenarios would be

- file size check returns true. Assert that the check was run once and the result is valid
- file size check returns false (n-1) times and true the nth time. Assert that the check was run n times and the result is valid
- file size check returns false. Assert that the check was run number of retries times and the result is invalid